# ASP.NET Callbacks with Friendly URLs and Routing

Tags: asp.net, routes, icallbackeventhandler

I have an ASP.NET custom server control that implements the ICallbackEventHandler to make callbacks to the server. I recently read an article (link below) that claims that page and control callback methods should not be used because they can cause issues with friendly URLs and routing. I did a limited test of this by including the Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls namespace in a test project and experienced no errors. I also tested using a gridview by enabling the EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks property and again experienced no problems. Are there circumstances where routing and friendly urls with callbacks could result in errors?

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/web-development-best-practices/what-not-to-do-in-aspnet,-and-what-to-do-instead